# c# objected disposed exception -how can I correct them?

Tags: c#, objectdisposedexception

I am beginner c#. 
I would like to make program converting from .wav file to .raw file.
I found some source and I would like to use it.
but something happened in the code. the error is related to ObjectDisposedException.

could you give me a some code or idea for me?
the whole code is under

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;

    namespace WaveTestRead
    {
       class WaveReader
       { 
    FileInfo m_fInfo;
    FileStream m_fStream;
    BinaryReader m_binReader;

    // RIFF chunk
    byte[] chunkID;
    UInt32 chunkSize;
    byte[] format;

    // fmt subchunk
    byte[] fmtChunkID;
    UInt32 fmtChunkSize;
    UInt16 audioFormat;
    UInt16 numChannels;
    UInt32 sampleRate;
    UInt32 byteRate;
    UInt16 blockAssign;
    UInt16 BitsPerSample;

    // data subchunk
    byte[] dataChunkID;
    UInt32 dataChunkSize;
    byte[] data8L;              // 8-bit left channel
    byte[] data8R;              // 8-bit right channel
    Int16[] data16L;           // 16-bit left channel
    Int16[] data16R;           // 16-bit right channel
    int numSamples;

    public WaveReader()
    {

    }

    public bool Open(String filename)
    {
        string str;
        m_fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
        m_fStream = m_fInfo.OpenRead();
        m_binReader = new BinaryReader(m_fStream);

        chunkID = new byte[4];
        format = new byte[4];

        chunkID = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4);
        chunkSize = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
        format = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4);

        str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(chunkID, 0, 4);
        if (str != "RIFF")
            return false;

        str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(format, 0, 4);
        if (str != "WAVE")
            return false;

        if (ReadFmt() == false)
            return false;
        if (ReadData() == false)
            return false;

        m_fStream.Close();

        return true;
    }

    private bool ReadFmt()
    {
        fmtChunkID = new byte[4];
        fmtChunkID = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4);

        string str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(fmtChunkID, 0, 4);
        if (str != "fmt ")
            return false;

        fmtChunkSize = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
        audioFormat = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();
        numChannels = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();
        sampleRate = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
        byteRate = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
        blockAssign = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();
        BitsPerSample = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();

        return true;
    }
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        p.Open("wavetest.wav");
        bool a = p.ReadFmt();
        p.ReadData();
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: The Open() function should not call m_fStream.Close().  This is not good code.

Comment: @Hans Passant Could you give me more precise explanation? I found error here    fmtChunkID = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4); and I checked the code "bool a = p.ReadFmt();" makes function reading twice. I think the first fuction call is okay but the second is not desirable. How I can just make function reading only one time?

Comment: Yes, that fails because m_binReader uses m_fStream.  Which was closed.

Comment: @HansPassant So Should I erase that m_fStream.close(); code ? or May I have the other way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely exists in `Main`.  The `Open` method closes the file at the end, and the `ReadFmt` call in Main reads from `m_binReader`.  Either don't call `ReadFmt` from your main method after the `Open` call, or change `Open` to not close the file when it's done (and make the close explicit).

It looks like `Open` is doing all the work for you anyway (by calling `ReadFmt` and `ReadData`).  You don't need to do it again in `Main`; just access the data from `p`.

Answer (score 1):

The code posted is not very well written.

Anyway you can try with these quick changes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace WaveTestRead
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var waveReader = new WaveReader())
            {
                if (!waveReader.Open("wavetest.wav"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to read file.");
                    return;
                }

                if (!waveReader.ReadFmt())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to read fmt.");
                    return;
                }

                // this method is not defined...
                //waveReader.ReadData();
            }

        }
    }

    class WaveReader : IDisposable
    {
        FileInfo m_fInfo;
        FileStream m_fStream;
        BinaryReader m_binReader;

        // RIFF chunk
        byte[] chunkID;
        UInt32 chunkSize;
        byte[] format;

        // fmt subchunk
        byte[] fmtChunkID;
        UInt32 fmtChunkSize;
        UInt16 audioFormat;
        UInt16 numChannels;
        UInt32 sampleRate;
        UInt32 byteRate;
        UInt16 blockAssign;
        UInt16 BitsPerSample;

        // data subchunk
        byte[] dataChunkID;
        UInt32 dataChunkSize;
        byte[] data8L;              // 8-bit left channel
        byte[] data8R;              // 8-bit right channel
        Int16[] data16L;           // 16-bit left channel
        Int16[] data16R;           // 16-bit right channel
        int numSamples;

        public WaveReader()
        {

        }

        public bool Open(String filename)
        {
            string str;
            m_fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
            m_fStream = m_fInfo.OpenRead();
            m_binReader = new BinaryReader(m_fStream);

            chunkID = new byte[4];
            format = new byte[4];

            chunkID = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4);
            chunkSize = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
            format = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4);

            str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(chunkID, 0, 4);
            if (str != "RIFF")
                return false;

            str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(format, 0, 4);
            if (str != "WAVE")
                return false;

            //if (ReadFmt() == false)
            //    return false;
            //if (ReadData() == false)
            //    return false;

            return true;
        }

        public bool ReadFmt()
        {
            fmtChunkID = new byte[4];
            fmtChunkID = m_binReader.ReadBytes(4);

            string str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(fmtChunkID, 0, 4);
            if (str != "fmt ")
                return false;

            fmtChunkSize = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
            audioFormat = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();
            numChannels = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();
            sampleRate = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
            byteRate = m_binReader.ReadUInt32();
            blockAssign = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();
            BitsPerSample = m_binReader.ReadUInt16();

            return true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_fStream != null)
                m_fStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have created a class WaveReader with your code and removed the internal call to ReadFmt. Then in the Main method I have checked the return code and in case of false I write to the console.